# Flutter: why ever use a Future over a Stream?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

If a Future displays a once off piece of data while a Stream offers the additional advantage of updating information in real-time when data is modified at the source (ie, Firestore database), then why would one ever use a Future? What disadvantages would using a Stream over a Future have?

Comment: When you don't need realtime.

Comment: But why not just use Stream always? And then, for example, do away with pull to refresh? I just want to know if there is a downside to only using Streams as opposed to Futures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would one ever use a Future?

A Future handles a single event when an asynchronous operation completes or fails. It can be used for simple HTTP requests (GET, POST, ...).

You can have a look to [the boring flutter development show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPmN4-i9zC8&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIK0r_D-zWcmJ1plIcDNnRkK) where Google engineers build a simple Hacker News app, with Futures.

**EDIT**

New [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc) from Flutter team about dart Futures

---

> What disadvantages would using a Stream over a Future have?

They are made for different needs : real time updates or asynchronous calls, so they cannot really be compared in terms of advantages of one over the other.